# Could not find hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I'm trying to learn how to use Hibernate. I have created a small project following a tutorial but when I try to run it, it throws this exception:
http://pastebin.com/pu2FnmmT

Seems to me `hibernate.cfg.xml` can not be found. I know this has probably been asked before, and all solutions say I have to place `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the /src folder. Which is what I did, but for some reason this error keeps popping up.

Beneath I've pasted the code involved:

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package util;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import model.Device;

public class HibernateUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        builder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistery = builder.build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistery);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Device device = new Device();
        device.setId(4);
        device.setName("Test Smart TV");

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(device);
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("Object saved successfully.....!!");
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
       <!-- Database connection settings -->
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poc</property>

       <!-- SQL dialect -->
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

       <!-- Echo all executed SQL to sysout -->
       <property name="show_sql">true</property>

       <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
       <!-- Mapping file -->
       <mapping resource="device.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My project structure is as follows:
https://puu.sh/tl50v/31cb4b0da9.png

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i wasn't able to respond during the weekend. I've fixed it, seems i downloaded a incorrect version of hibernate which didn't contain all the needed .JAR files.

After replacing those it worked like a charm. Thanks for your help guys! 
Case closed!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your code using eclipse "Run As > Java Application" Option ... put the file (`hibernate.cfg.xml`) as a silibing file of the `src` folder...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But it's already there, as shown here: https://puu.sh/tl50v/31cb4b0da9.png. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: According to your picture, `hibernate.cfg.xml` is under src !! it should be at the same level of src folder in your project !

Answer (score 0):

Did you put:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="model">
```

in device.hbm.xml ?

And check if your jar are correctly in your project.

When i use hibernate i don't give "hibernate.cfg.xml" in configure and i put

1. connection.driver_class
2. connection.username
3. connection.password
4. connection.url

without hibernate.